# QT system try icon with a window

Tags: c++, qt, icons, tray

I want to open a new window aligned with the try icon (as the built-in volume control does)! :/

I found something about QRect QSystemTrayIcon::geometry()

But idk how to use it

Comment: Well, if you check the QRect-documentation, you will see that it gives you x/y coordinates (on the screen) and a width and height parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Qt::Popup flags on your widget.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/6632/use-of-popup-window

```
QWidget* popupWidget = new QWidget();
popupWidget->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup);
```

Pretty much anything else has a lot of corner cases that are hard to cover, like if your window is too tall, goes off the edge of the screen, etc.

Hope that helps.